# How to bundle a local gem that I created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I had use jeweler to create a gem skeleton and wrote some come on it. Now ... how can i put it in my gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the 'path' option:

```
 gem "my_gem", :path => "relative_path_goes_here"
```